# Android Studio : Network Inspector shows nothing after updating in bumblebee

Tags: android, android-studio, retrofit, profiler, android-studio-bumblebee

Network inspector show no network calls after updating Android Studio in bumblebee.

I have tried so many things but shows nothing.

Android Studio Version : `Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1`

Networking Library : `Retrofit`

[image]